# I cannot install the IBM Cloud CLI

Tags: installation, ibm-cloud, command-line-interface, watson

I am trying to get started building a voice interface with Watson Assistant, and following the docs I need to install the IBM Cloud CLI. I have downloaded the three latest versions from here (https://console.bluemix.net/docs/cli/reference/bluemix_cli/all_versions.html) but the installs all fail. I tried running the command line install as well, but that fails too:

```
Download complete. Executing installer...
installer: Package name is IBM Cloud Command Line Interface
installer: Installing at base path /
installer: The install failed (The Installer encountered an error that 
caused the installation to fail. Contact the software manufacturer for 
assistance.)
Install failed.
```

I tried installing on Macintosh HD disk and in a project folder, but it all fails! Help?

I tried versions 0.6.6, 0.6.5, and 0.6.4. I am running macOS High Sierra 10.13.3.

Comment: What version number?

Comment: @fastasleep What is your Mac OS Version?

Comment: @akaykay I tried 0.6.6, 0.6.5, and 0.6.4.

Comment: @joe macOS version 10.13.3

Comment: @fastasleep What are the permissions on your root folder?

Comment: @joe Not entirely sure what I'm doing, but if I open Terminal and type `cd /` and then type `ls -ld`, I see: `drwxr-xr-x  31 root  wheel  992 Feb 25 14:31 .`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pls see if there is /usr/local/bin directory in your OS. If not, create the directory and install again.

This will be fixed in next release v0.6.7.

Comment: If I type `cd /` into Terminal, and then `cd usr` then `cd local`, that's all good, but when I type `cd bin` I get `no such file or directory`. How do I go about creating it correctly?

Comment: @fastasleep Do `mkdir /usr/local/bin` - that will create a new directory if nothing exists.